# Verification link with email and hashed user id with salt string. Is it secure?

Tags: php, hash, email-verification

what do you think about creating a verification link having a querystring made up with parameters as `email` and `hash`?

- email is the html encoded plain string email of the registered user,
- hash is the result value of the PHP function `password_hash` where the string for the first parameter is the unique id user number selected from the database with a fixed salt string.

I was thinking about also to toggle the salt, but one can guess the id user number for a given email, passing it to `password_hash` and obtaining a valid hash for the querystring (even if password_hash adds automatically a salt on his own.), so I think it isn't secure.

I thought something like this:

```
// the result of SELECT from the database (I use Mysql)
$id    = '5';
// fixed salt string
$salt  = 'xbrENiBq6kb87WrZYhxS';
$email = urlencode($email);
$key   = $id . $salt;
$hash  = urlencode(password_hash($key, PASSWORD_DEFAULT));

// the resulted querystring:
$url = "somesite.com/index.php?email=$email&hash=$hash";
```

then I will send that to the user email.

Please, can you tell me, what do you think about? Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your encoding, you can try with mixing up various types of encode to reach to the real value. Your final result to compare with the database must be a `md5` string, this way you don't lose performance as well.

```
SELECT md5(your_field) FROM table
```

Sorry for the bad English.

Comment: No need to be sorry for you bad english. But you should also put ` around your code to format it nicely.